# Socrata get data types of dataset columns

Tags: socrata

Using the API how can i get the data types for the columns of a dataset?

I am creating a application to import data sets into an SQL database, an automated way to find the data types would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest place is to find that in the headers of the response itself. Check out the `X-SODA2-Types` header in [this sample response](http://www.hurl.it/?method=GET&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdata.cityofchicago.org%2Fresource%2Falternative-fuel-locations.json&headers=%7B%22X-App-Token%22%3A%5B%22bjp8KrRvAPtuf809u1UXnI0Z8%22%5D%7D&args=%7B%22fuel_type_code%22%3A%5B%22LPG%22%5D%7D)

I'm checking with our engineering team to see whether `X-SODA2-Types` is really deprecated, as per the warning.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by chrismetcalf still works, but there is now a new endpoint and due to CORS, the headers he mentions may not be accessible via AJAX requests.

```
https://<socrata.host>/api/views/<4x4>.json
```

As an example, the https://data.lacity.org/api/views/yv23-pmwf.json dataset contains a `columns` array with definitions for all of the columns including their data type.

Comment: yes, it works for me. I get column type and name from this api.

Answer (score 1):

Socrata SODA api: you will need 2 type of URL,

1. Get meta data, such as column name and type, use  api/views

   ```
       https://data.lacity.org/api/views/yv23-pmwf.json
   ```
2. Get real row data, use api/id

   ```
       https://data.lacity.org/api/id/yv23-pmwf.json
   ```

Example:
https://data.countyofriverside.us/api/views/35yn-v8ur.json

each columns, name, type was highlighted

[image]